# InvalidArgumentException with Custom Forms extension by Plugin Company

Tags: magento2.4.4

I have a M2.4.4 with several Amasty extensions and one Plugin.Company extension called custom forms. I set up two simple forms and I am getting a InvalidArgumentException error when I submit the form. Upon form submission I get a copy of the email using an Amasty SMTP extension with the subject line:

Error filtering template: Argument 'value' must be type of string, object given.

Additionally the google captcha doesn't work with this extension either.

I tried contacting the extension developer and never heard back.

Below is a copy of system.log. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
[2022-08-15T03:08:14.571505+00:00] main.CRITICAL: InvalidArgumentException: Argument 'value' must be type of string, NULL given. in /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Filter/Template.php:177
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Template/Filter.php(1106): Magento\Framework\Filter\Template->filter()
#1 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Email\Model\Template\Filter->filter()
#2 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Email\Model\Template\Filter\Interceptor->___callParent()
#3 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Email\Model\Template\Filter\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#4 /opt/magecw/m2/generated/code/Magento/Email/Model/Template/Filter/Interceptor.php(32): Magento\Email\Model\Template\Filter\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#5 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/plugincompany/contactforms/Model/Template/Filter.php(257): Magento\Email\Model\Template\Filter\Interceptor->filter()
#6 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/plugincompany/contactforms/Model/Entry.php(615): PluginCompany\ContactForms\Model\Template\Filter->filterForEmail()
#7 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/plugincompany/contactforms/Model/Entry.php(595): PluginCompany\ContactForms\Model\Entry->filterVar()
#8 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/plugincompany/contactforms/Model/Entry.php(587): PluginCompany\ContactForms\Model\Entry->initSubmissionParameterFromForm()
#9 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/plugincompany/contactforms/Model/Entry.php(536): PluginCompany\ContactForms\Model\Entry->getFilteredSubmissionFieldValue()
#10 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/plugincompany/contactforms/Model/Entry.php(204): PluginCompany\ContactForms\Model\Entry->getAdminBcc()
#11 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/plugincompany/contactforms/Controller/Form/Submit.php(243): PluginCompany\ContactForms\Model\Entry->initFromSubmittedData()
#12 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/plugincompany/contactforms/Controller/Form/Submit.php(179): PluginCompany\ContactForms\Controller\Form\Submit->getEntryWithSubmissionData()
#13 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/plugincompany/contactforms/Controller/Form/Submit.php(157): PluginCompany\ContactForms\Controller\Form\Submit->notifyAdmin()
#14 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/plugincompany/contactforms/Controller/Form/Submit.php(128): PluginCompany\ContactForms\Controller\Form\Submit->runExecute()
#15 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): PluginCompany\ContactForms\Controller\Form\Submit->execute()
#16 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): PluginCompany\ContactForms\Controller\Form\Submit\Interceptor->___callParent()
#17 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): PluginCompany\ContactForms\Controller\Form\Submit\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#18 /opt/magecw/m2/generated/code/PluginCompany/ContactForms/Controller/Form/Submit/Interceptor.php(23): PluginCompany\ContactForms\Controller\Form\Submit\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#19 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(111): PluginCompany\ContactForms\Controller\Form\Submit\Interceptor->execute()
#20 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch()
#21 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): PluginCompany\ContactForms\Controller\Form\Submit\Interceptor->___callParent()
#22 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): PluginCompany\ContactForms\Controller\Form\Submit\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#23 /opt/magecw/m2/generated/code/PluginCompany/ContactForms/Controller/Form/Submit/Interceptor.php(32): PluginCompany\ContactForms\Controller\Form\Submit\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#24 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(245): PluginCompany\ContactForms\Controller\Form\Submit\Interceptor->dispatch()
#25 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(212): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->getActionResponse()
#26 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(147): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest()
#27 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch()
#28 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent()
#29 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(99): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#30 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch()
#31 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(75): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#32 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch()
#33 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin\Interceptor->___callParent()
#34 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#35 /opt/magecw/m2/generated/code/Magento/PageCache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#36 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin\Interceptor->aroundDispatch()
#37 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#38 /opt/magecw/m2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#39 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch()
#40 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(264): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#41 /opt/magecw/m2/pub/index.php(30): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run()
#42 {main} [] []




[2022-08-15T03:08:14.572398+00:00] main.CRITICAL: InvalidArgumentException: Argument 'value' must be type of string, object given. in /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Filter/Template.php:177
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Template/Filter.php(1106): Magento\Framework\Filter\Template->filter()
#1 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Email\Model\Template\Filter->filter()
#2 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Email\Model\Template\Filter\Interceptor->___callParent()
#3 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Email\Model\Template\Filter\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#4 /opt/magecw/m2/generated/code/Magento/Email/Model/Template/Filter/Interceptor.php(32): Magento\Email\Model\Template\Filter\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#5 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/plugincompany/contactforms/Model/Template/Filter.php(257): Magento\Email\Model\Template\Filter\Interceptor->filter()
#6 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/plugincompany/contactforms/Model/Entry.php(615): PluginCompany\ContactForms\Model\Template\Filter->filterForEmail()
#7 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/plugincompany/contactforms/Model/Entry.php(595): PluginCompany\ContactForms\Model\Entry->filterVar()
#8 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/plugincompany/contactforms/Model/Entry.php(587): PluginCompany\ContactForms\Model\Entry->initSubmissionParameterFromForm()
#9 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/plugincompany/contactforms/Model/Entry.php(553): PluginCompany\ContactForms\Model\Entry->getFilteredSubmissionFieldValue()
#10 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/plugincompany/contactforms/Model/Entry.php(206): PluginCompany\ContactForms\Model\Entry->getAdminSubject()
#11 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/plugincompany/contactforms/Controller/Form/Submit.php(243): PluginCompany\ContactForms\Model\Entry->initFromSubmittedData()
#12 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/plugincompany/contactforms/Controller/Form/Submit.php(179): PluginCompany\ContactForms\Controller\Form\Submit->getEntryWithSubmissionData()
#13 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/plugincompany/contactforms/Controller/Form/Submit.php(157): PluginCompany\ContactForms\Controller\Form\Submit->notifyAdmin()
#14 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/plugincompany/contactforms/Controller/Form/Submit.php(128): PluginCompany\ContactForms\Controller\Form\Submit->runExecute()
#15 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): PluginCompany\ContactForms\Controller\Form\Submit->execute()
#16 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): PluginCompany\ContactForms\Controller\Form\Submit\Interceptor->___callParent()
#17 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): PluginCompany\ContactForms\Controller\Form\Submit\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#18 /opt/magecw/m2/generated/code/PluginCompany/ContactForms/Controller/Form/Submit/Interceptor.php(23): PluginCompany\ContactForms\Controller\Form\Submit\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#19 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(111): PluginCompany\ContactForms\Controller\Form\Submit\Interceptor->execute()
#20 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch()
#21 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): PluginCompany\ContactForms\Controller\Form\Submit\Interceptor->___callParent()
#22 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): PluginCompany\ContactForms\Controller\Form\Submit\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#23 /opt/magecw/m2/generated/code/PluginCompany/ContactForms/Controller/Form/Submit/Interceptor.php(32): PluginCompany\ContactForms\Controller\Form\Submit\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#24 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(245): PluginCompany\ContactForms\Controller\Form\Submit\Interceptor->dispatch()
#25 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(212): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->getActionResponse()
#26 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(147): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest()
#27 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch()
#28 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent()
#29 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(99): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#30 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch()
#31 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(75): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#32 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch()
#33 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin\Interceptor->___callParent()
#34 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#35 /opt/magecw/m2/generated/code/Magento/PageCache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#36 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin\Interceptor->aroundDispatch()
#37 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#38 /opt/magecw/m2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#39 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch()
#40 /opt/magecw/m2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(264): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#41 /opt/magecw/m2/pub/index.php(30): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run()
#42 {main} [] []
```

Comment: This means that in method `PluginCompany\ContactForms\Model\Template\Filter->filterForEmail()` uses incorrect data for call `filter` in `\Magento\Framework\Filter\Template`. The system expects the argument should be `string`, but  you pass `null`. You can try to fix yourself or contact ** PluginCompany** support with this error.

Comment: Thank you Victor. It turned out that their extension doesn't have logic to account for a subject line being undefined.